# How to use CSS floats or JS to re-order and set fixed width blocks for a sequence of <a> and <em><a> elements that I cannot edit?

Tags: javascript, css

I have output from a 'black box' generating content that I need to re-order and align and style..... The sourcecode output is more or less like this:

```
 <div class="wrapper">
    <aside id="black_box" class="widget black_box">
        <ul class="news">                               
            <li> 
                auto content 1 
                <a href="URL1a"> link 1a</a>
                content 1 more
                <a href="URL1b"> link 1b</a>                        
                <br/>
                <em>
                    <a href="URL_never_changes">date of article</a>
                    </em>
            </li>
                        <li> 
                auto content 2 
                <a href="URL2a"> link 2a</a>                        
                <br/>
                <em>
                <em>
                    <a href="URL_never_changes">date of article</a>
                    </em>
            </li>
```

Before styling, it outputs this:

**Content 1 Link 1a content 1 more link 1b

date of article

auto content 2 link 2a

date of article**

and so forth (more repetitions)..... With a little CSS styling I got partway....:

```
.news br {display:none;  }
.news li em a { float: left; display:block;  margin: 0px 70px 0px 0px;  }
.news li {clear:both;  }
```

Results in this (note reversed content order!):

**short autocontent_*_*_Content 1 Link 1a content 1 more link 1b

short autocontent2_*_*__auto content 2 link 2a**

The problem: I want the second column of content to be left-justified and aligned. But I can't get the  block to act like a block and take up a fixed width space. Instead, the non-em content begins at the 70px margin (em-blcok width has no effect).

Any suggestions?
Thanks, Dave

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. A jsFiddle would be really helpful for exactly understanding your question, since it is kind of complicated.

Comment: Visit http://jsfiddle.net/user/signup/ .

Comment: I don't full understand what you're trying to accomplish. Can you provide more detail?